# Struts2 prepare methods

Tags: java, struts2

I have one action class with different methods mapped for each action in my struts.xml.
And I want different prepare methods invoked before my other methods mapped in the struts.xml.

Comment: can;t you simply invoke  `prepare` method from action

Answer (score 5):

Simply create a

```
void prepareMethodName(){}
```

Where MethodName is the name of your per-method Preparable method.  The prepare() method by default will still run after this method is called.

Please see: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/prepare-interceptor.html